# React App SyntaxError: Use of reserved word 'let' in strict mode in Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, safari

I read a lot of articles about that Safari 5.1 is old and this mistake is caused by it - this old version of Safari does not support ES6. But I have really big application created with react-create-app and there is no problem at all except this part of the code:

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, ...rest }) {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={function(props) {
        return sessionStorage.getItem("Token") ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to="/login" />
        );
      }}
    />
  );
}
export default PrivateRoute;
```

This is private route and in Safari console I see:

[image]

Not sure how to change my code to avoid this **let Component = _ref.component**. I tried passing arguments in this way { Component, ...rest } but the effect is the same. Even more - when I delete Component + case in return, there is the same error for rest. Any ideas how I can change my code to make it possible to Safari to read it? 
P.S.: The code is working fine for all other browsers.

Comment: Hasn't Safari 5.1 been unsupported for almost 7 years?

Comment: Yes, it is. I know it is out of support but I am wondering if there is a way to make code works on it.

Comment: Yes, you will need to target older browsers in your webpack config,.. If you just want to sort for this you could add the specific babel plugin -> https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-block-scoping

Comment: The solution is probably in your build configuration, but I'm not familiar with how that works with React.

Comment: ps.  If your using `babel-env`,  try -> `safari >= 5`, .